# Trying to convert geoJSONString into drawingTools layer

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

In earth engine code editor, how do I convert the following geoJSONString which contains two simple polygons (but *could* be a polygon and a linestring, or a polygon and a point, etc.) into an EE GeometryCollection that can be added to Map.drawingTools().addLayer

```
var myJSON = "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[-92.15900326894578,37.589595840748565],[-85.74298764394578,34.46281418503638],[-81.34845639394578,35.970623685271086],[-92.15900326894578,37.589595840748565]]],\"evenOdd\":true},{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[-96.81720639394578,35.3278510601514],[-102.00275326894578,33.14831091823538],[-96.90509701894578,32.112074763487286],[-96.81720639394578,35.3278510601514]]],\"evenOdd\":true}"
```

I saw this "Fixed issue using the pure GeoJSON ee.Geometry(string) constructor when given a GeometryCollection. The elements may now have their own crs/geodesic/evenOdd fields, so long as they all have the same values." here https://developers.google.cn/earth-engine/changelog

I tried this:

```
Map.drawingTools().addLayer(ee.Geometry(myJSON));
```

And get this error:

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'type' in
> {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":....

Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/862617c8fb1ad3207254fae775bbac12

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two things going wrong.

**Invalid GeoJSON**: you have two polygons so type should be `"MultiPolygon"` which requires an array of polygon coordinates.

```
var myJSON = "{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[-92.15900326894578,37.589595840748565],[-85.74298764394578,34.46281418503638],[-81.34845639394578,35.970623685271086],[-92.15900326894578,37.589595840748565]]],[[[-96.81720639394578,35.3278510601514],[-102.00275326894578,33.14831091823538],[-96.90509701894578,32.112074763487286],[-96.81720639394578,35.3278510601514]]]],\"evenOdd\":true}";
```

**String parsing**: parse the string with `JSON.parse`.

```
Map.drawingTools().addLayer([JSON.parse(myJSON)]);
```

Combined together should work.

```
var myJSON = "{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[-92.15900326894578,37.589595840748565],[-85.74298764394578,34.46281418503638],[-81.34845639394578,35.970623685271086],[-92.15900326894578,37.589595840748565]]],[[[-96.81720639394578,35.3278510601514],[-102.00275326894578,33.14831091823538],[-96.90509701894578,32.112074763487286],[-96.81720639394578,35.3278510601514]]]],\"evenOdd\":true}";
Map.drawingTools().addLayer([JSON.parse(myJSON)]);
```

Comment: Thanks @JustinBraaten that does work.  I should have asked the question a little differently.  Rather than this being a multipolygon, let's say it is a geoJSON that has some combination of linestrings, points, polygons, etc.  Do you know how I would rework it so that the myJSON var remains as two polygons in the above example (or a polyline and a polygon, etc.).  Hope that makes sense...

Comment: I edited my question for hopefully more clarity :)

Comment: I see, I think the type you need then is "GeometryCollection" (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#appendix-A.7). With a quick test I could not get it to work in EE, though. It's possible it is not supported.

Comment: It seems like EE has some sort of support for this because when you print the result of drawingTools.layers().get(0).toGeometry().evaluate(function(result) it shows "GeometryCollection" and also I notice there is ee.Algorithms.GeometryConstructors.MultiGeometry that says it "Constructs a MultiGeometry from the given list of geometry elements".  I just can't seem to determine what format the geoJSON needs to be in to convert it to a MultiGeometry.  I'll keep trying, but open to ideas...